# Code works then stops working when adding more code

Tags: list, python-3.x, integer, undefined

I have written this code and it completely worked but when I added the last 2 lines , it kept on saying  : 'Total' is not defined.Without the last 2 lines the code works perfect , what is causing this ?

```
NumGiven=''
while not NumGiven.isnumeric():
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
while len(NumGiven)<7 or len(NumGiven)>8:
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
if len(NumGiven)==8:
    my_list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven]
    total=(sum([int(i) for i in NumGiven]))
ans = total / 10.0

if total % 10 == 0:
    print("Your GTIN8 code is correct.")
else:
    print("Your GTIN8 code is incorrect")
if len(NumGiven)==7:
    my_list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven]
    print(my_list)
```

Comment: Because you're using `NumGiven` with lengths other than 8. `total` will only be defined `if len(NumGiven)==8:`

Comment: So what can I do ? I need to use the variable `NumGiven`

Comment: That depends on what you want `total` to be if the length of `NumGiven` is 7.

Comment: Ordinarly, one would give an initial value to the variable at the beginning of the code so that it would always be defined, but I'm not entirely sure what you're attempting to do here.

Comment: I am just asking the user to enter a 7 or 8 digit number and if it 8 then it would add all 8 digits together and divide by 10 , if the answer has a remainder then the code(the 8 digit number) they have given is incorrect.But if the user enters 7 digits then it will workout the positions of the numbers if the position is odd (1,3,5 and 7) then multiply by 3 and if even then multiply by 1. Then add the new multiplied 7 digits and subtract from the closest multiple of 10 , which will give use the 8th digit for the given 7 digit number.

Comment: Then you only want to assign (and use) `total` **if** the length is 8, right? The way you have it now, you're doing both even if the length is *not* 8. By the way, your clarification should really be an edit to the original question.

Comment: My code excepts a length of 7 or 8 and I haven't used `total` in  my approach `if NumGiven==7:` so why is `total` effecting it ?

Comment: You have used `total` in your approach if `NumGiven != 8`. Remove the code for 7, enter a number with 7 digits and you'll get the same error. If you want code to be executed only if some condition is true, you have to include *all* of that code in the `if` block. Trace through your code for both cases (7 and 8 digits).

Comment: I can't use the same `if` block for both numbers, because they both need different actions to occur.like I explained above(big paragraph).Instead of wasting your time talking to me , you could've just showed me how to do it.

Comment: Indent lines 9 through 14 by 4 spaces. Have a nice day.

Comment: just gives me blank line

Answer (score 0):

Structure your code this way:

```
NumGiven=''
while not NumGiven.isnumeric():
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
while len(NumGiven)<7 or len(NumGiven)>8:
    NumGiven=(input('Please enter a 7 or 8 digit number:'))
if len(NumGiven) == 8:
    my_list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven]
    total=(sum([int(i) for i in NumGiven]))
    ans = total / 10.0

    if total % 10 == 0:
        print("Your GTIN8 code is correct.")
    else:
        print("Your GTIN8 code is incorrect")
elif len(NumGiven) == 7:
    my_list=[int(i) for i in NumGiven]
    print(my_list)
```